# GraalVM and Resources in combination with ImageRegistry (JFace)

Tags: java, jface, graalvm

I am using the ImageRegistry in our project to manage image resources.

AOT-Compilation with GraalVM packs all resources in the native-image with the directive 
`-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles` That works fine.

**BUT**: Is there a way to iterate over all resources during runtime, cause I have to put them all into the ImageRegistry. Just want to avoid a manually add-add-add...

Previously it was done by iterating over the jars in the classpath during runtime and filtering the desired resources and add them to the ImageRegistry.

**BUT**: Since we have now a native-image this mechanism won't work anymore.

Any hints?